# tarfile.open overwrites the file everytime

Tags: python

I am trying to create python script to archive and compress one year old data in datewise tar file. Script is also generating log file of the archived files. I am using python 2.6 on linux.

Here is my code :

```
for search_date in dd_list:
    tar_file = "/files/yearly_archive/nas_archive_" + search_date + ".tgz"
    mytar = tarfile.open(tar_file,"w:gz")
    log_file = "/files/yearly_archive/archive_log_" + search_date
    fcount = 0
    #print tar_file
    #print log_file
    f = open(log_file,'ab+')
    for f_name, d_date in date_file_dict.iteritems():
        if d_date == search_date:
            #print f_name
            fcount += 1
            mytar.add(f_name)
            f.write(f_name + '\n')
    date_occur_dict[search_date] = fcount
    mytar.close()
    f.close()
```

Here log file is getting appended if it exists but tar file is getting overwritten every when I run the script. Is there a way I can make sure tar file gets appended if it exists otherwise gets created ?

Edit :

I tried to add code for ungzipping and adding but it is not working.

```
for search_date in dd_list:
    tar_file = "/files/yearly_archive/nas_archive_" + search_date + ".tgz"
    zip = 1
    try:
        with open(tar_file,'ab+'):
            import gzip
            d_tar = gzip.open(tar_file,'wb')
            zip = 0
    except IOError:
        print "Creating new tar file"
    if zip == 1:
        mytar = tarfile.open(tar_file,"w:gz")
    else:
        mytar = tarfile.open(d_tar,"w")
    log_file = "/files/yearly_archive/archive_log_" + search_date
    fcount = 0
    #print tar_file
    #print log_file
    f = open(log_file,'ab+')
    for f_name, d_date in date_file_dict.iteritems():
        if d_date == search_date:
            #print f_name
            fcount += 1
            mytar.add(f_name)
            f.write(f_name + '\n')
    date_occur_dict[search_date] = fcount
    mytar.close()
    f.close()
```

I am getting following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sort_archive.py", line 63, in <module>
    mytar = tarfile.open(d_tar,"w")
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tarfile.py", line 1687, in open
    return cls.taropen(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tarfile.py", line 1697, in taropen
    return cls(name, mode, fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/tarfile.py", line 1518, in __init__
    fileobj = bltn_open(name, self._mode)
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, instance found
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `tarfile` to append to compressed tarballs. Either perform the decompress/compress steps separately, or don't use compression in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean unzipping before adding file and then use tarfile.open(tar_file,"a") to append tar file??

Comment: I have doubts about ungzipping and appending. When we open file by gzip.open will the file name remain same? If i add files after opening with gzip will it go to tar?

Comment: `gzip.open()` will not change the filename.

Comment: after writing to the file do I have to gzip it again or as file name already contains .tgz it will be gzipped automatically?

Comment: You mean writing to the file returned by `gzip.open()`?

Comment: yes. Shall I use gzip.writelines or tar.add() method to append?

Answer (score 0):

< strikethrough >

Did you try to change the mode ? I see w, which clearly overwrites the file. Try with a, or w+.

```
mytar = tarfile.open(tar_file,"w+:gz")
```

or

```
mytar = tarfile.open(tar_file,"a:gz")
```

< / strikethrough >

Comment: Like [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html) say, you cannot use `'a'` with `':gz'` or `':bz2'`, and `'w+'` is invalid.